# Solving $\int \frac{4x^2-3x+2}{4x^2-4x+3}$ with partial fractions

Tags: integration

I'm trying to understand how my textbook solved this problem but something seems a bit off.

First thing to do was to perform long division since the degree of the numerator is not less than the degree of the denominator, such a division yielded:

$$1 + \frac{x-1}{4x^2-4x-3}$$

Calculating this integral, we got to the point where it seemed plausible to do a substitution $u = 2x - 1$

$$x + \frac{1}{2} \int\frac{\frac{1}{2}(u + 1) -1}{u^2+2}du$$

Now, here's the tricky part, somehow the next simplification was:
$$x + \frac{1}{4} \int\frac{(u -1)}{u^2+2}du$$

My question is how did he do this?

Comment: Now you could write $\frac{u-1}{u^2+2}= \frac{1}{2}*\frac{2u}{u^2+2} - \frac{1}{2}*\frac{2}{u^2+2}$.
The first integral should be easy to compute, because in the nominator there stands the derivative of the denominator, so you geht that the integral of $\frac{2u}{u^2+2}$ is $ln(u^2+2)$. For the second integral, you can write $\frac{1}{2}*\frac{2}{u^2+2}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\frac{u^2}{2}+1}$. Now substitute $s^2=\frac{u^2}{2}$ and note that the integral of $\frac{1}{s^2+1}=arctan(s)$. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}(u+1)-1\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}u-\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{4}(u-1)$

Comment: Thats the third time today that I have been writing an answer and then someone else answers it

Comment: @Seth In my opinion, if you were going to finish your answer within few seconds you should be feel free to post it.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

We have that

$$\frac{4x^2-3x+2}{4x^2-4x+3}=\frac{4x^2-4x+3+x-1}{4x^2-4x+3}=1+\frac{x-1}{4x^2-4x+3}=$$

$$=1+\frac18\frac{8x-4-4}{4x^2-4x+3}=1+\frac18\frac{8x-4}{4x^2-4x+3}-\frac12\frac{1}{4x^2-4x+3}$$

$$=1+\frac18\frac{8x-4-4}{4x^2-4x+3}=1+\frac18\frac{8x-4}{4x^2-4x+3}-\frac12\frac{1}{2+(2x-1)^2}$$